# Preserving RPM database for containers

Tags: docker, containers, rpm

How to preserve RPM database for RPMs installation that happened after the container is spin up? I know installing RPMs inside running container is anti pattern, but we need this.
RPMs should be bundled with Image itself, but in our case, requirement is to preserve the installation happened after container spin up.

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process; like any other process, its environment disappears after the container exits.  What single process needs to dynamically install packages as it's running, and recreate that environment later?  Can you move the `RUN yum install` commands inside your Dockerfile?  Or are you trying to set up a virtual machine with a persistent disk?

Comment: Yes, its like virtual machine with a persistent disk based on RockyLinux docker image

Comment: A standard virtual-machine setup might meet your needs better.  What leads to Docker as a technology choice?  Is this a programming-related question at all; do you have any application source code that could be part of the question, for example?

Comment: We have existing product which have multiple services which get runs using systemd. We want to migrate that all in one services to single container in first release. Down the line, we will separate each service in its own container.